# Error 1004 while creating Pivot Table on Dynamic data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am experiencing the following issue while creating Pivot table using VBA. The source data is dynamic. While creating Pivot table I receive following error sometimes and it works fine.

> Run-time error '1004':
>   The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.

```
'pivot table


'Adding new worksheet
Set ws = wbReport.Worksheets.add

'Set rangept = Sheets("Non_Complaince_CHOC_CA").UsedRange.Select
 'ls = wbReport.Sheets(ReportSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ls = wbReport.Sheets(ReportSheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Creating Pivot cache
Set pc = wbReport.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "" & ReportSheet & "!r1c1:r" & ls & "c12")


'Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "rangept")



'Creating Pivot table
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.Range("B3"))

'Setting Fields
With pt.PivotFields("Downtime Requirement")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With


'set value field

With pt.PivotFields("Downtime Requirement")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlCount
    .Position = 1
End With
ws.Name = "Failing_PI_Summary"

ws.Range("B2:C2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Prod Domain Failing PI Summary for " & Client
    ws.Range("B2:C2").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbReport.Save
'end pivot table
```

Comment: The error prompt already gave you the hints. Source data should always contain a `Valid Contiguous Header` with at least 1 row of data. Else, you cannot create a `Pivot Table`.

Comment: The data is dynamic and it always has a header. I am unsure why I am able to get the pivot table created sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Check the value of `ls`. It should not be equal to 1. Or the best way to update a dynamic Pivot table is: `1. Use a table as source. 2. Use a dynamic named Range. `